# What is the difference between using hook_views_pre_render() or preprocess functions?

Tags: 7, views, hooks, theming

What is the difference in using hook_views_pre_render(&$view) instead of using 
[THEME_NAME]_preprocess_views_view_table_[VIEW_NAME] . I am just changing the '#markup' of field.
hook_views_pre_render() is being used in custom module and 
[THEME_NAME]_preprocess_views_view_table_[VIEW_NAME] is used in template.php file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Behind the scenes they're pretty different (one is a hook provided by Views, the other part of the theme system). Practically speaking, as a module/theme developer you'll see very little difference. What you can do in one you can do in the other, and `hook_views_pre_render()` can even be implemented in a theme.

I'd say just pick the one which offers you the most intuitive/simple way to make the changes you need to. If the theme preprocess requires more complex logic/code use the pre_render hook, and vice versa.

Comment: So with regards to performance they are both the same ..?

Comment: Yeah, you're just manipulating variables in an array/object in both so I can't see there being much difference. Both hooks are invoked for other modules regardless of whether your module/theme implements them, so the difference in speed will be negligible. If you're running a Facebook-sized app then you might want to profile it - otherwise that would fall under the bracket of micro-optimisation IMO. But then if you're running a Facebook-sized app you won't be using Drupal ;)